# Value Error single feature (y, y_train) needs 2D array in digit recognizer train, fit/prediction OneVsRest classifier for Logistic

Tags: python, arrays, machine-learning, prediction

**Problem**
To perform prediction multi-class on digit-recognizer, data based on Kaggle data set.

Setting up OneVsRest classifier for multi-class prediction on digits using Logistic Regression and using RandomizedSearchCV for
best estimate and params, all working so far good.

Fit my model using the RandomizedSearchCV parameter grid results. The setup a new LogisticRegression multi-class to build models on OneVsRestClassifier.

Fit model is generated. Then use OneVsRestClassifier model to perform predict() on y. I know that reshaping is required before running a model. But what shape shall be appropriate with y, or y_train, when there is only one value, e.g, the 'label' value.

This is where the problem on ValueError occurs on ValueError that Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[9 8 9 ... 8 8 8]. When I reshape y: y = np.array(y).reshape(1, -1), then I get "ValueError: X has 4125 features, but LogisticRegression is expecting 785 features as input."

I goofed, up, need code in setting up correct shape for prediction model using either y response or y_train. Both y, and y_train data has a single feature. So how does one use array.reshape(-1, 1) on a single feature (y, y_train) to create a 2D for the expected 2D array in the model execution?

**Shape**
y and y_train both has shape (4125,). X_train_scaled is shape (4125, 785)

**Code for OneVsResst Classifier**

```
train = pd.read_csv("../data/DigitRecognizer/train.csv")
test = pd.read_csv("../data/DigitRecognizer/test.csv")
train = train.loc[(train['label'] > 3) & (train['label'] > 7)]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(train, y, test_size=0.50, random_state=42)
y = X_train['label']
df = X_train.drop(['label'], axis=1)
ovr_model = OneVsRestClassifier(LogisticRegression())
param_grid = {
    'estimator__max_iter' : [2500, 4500, 6500, 9500, 14000],
    'estimator__C': [0.1, 1, 100, 200]
}
ovr_grid_param = RandomizedSearchCV(ovr_model, param_grid, cv=5, n_jobs=3, error_score="raise")
min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
X_train_scaled = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(X_train)

ovr_fit = ovr_grid_param.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train) 
print("\n OVR best estimator search result:\n", ovr_fit.best_estimator_)
print("\n OVR best score search result:\n", ovr_fit.best_score_)
print("\n OVR best parameters search result:\n", ovr_fit.best_params_)
    
ovr_model_best = OneVsRestClassifier(LogisticRegression(multi_class='ovr', C=200, max_iter=9500, solver='liblinear'))
ovr_model_best_fit = ovr_model_best.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train)

y = np.array(y).reshape(1, -1)
 
ovr_model_best_pred = ovr_model_best_fit.predict(y)
ovr_score = cross_val_score(ovr_model_best, X_train, y_train, cv=3, scoring="accuracy")
```

**Error Logistic Model expecting**

```
ValueError: X has 4125 features, but LogisticRegression is expecting 785 features as input.
```

**2D Value Error on predict**

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[9 8 9 ... 8 8 8].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

**Data X_train_scaled**

```
array([[1., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       ...,
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

**Data y_train**

```
35436    9
24713    8
37408    9
22832    9
23308    9
22425    9
28629    9
6296     9
32284    9
5523     8
19412    9
23756    9
38163    9
34117    9
15413    9
5722     8
32083    8
31210    9
26297    9
23171    8
Name: label, dtype: int64
```

**Data y**

```
35436    9
24713    8
37408    9
22832    9
23308    9
22425    9
28629    9
6296     9
32284    9
5523     8
19412    9
23756    9
38163    9
34117    9
15413    9
5722     8
32083    8
31210    9
26297    9
23171    8
Name: label, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to use the X_test which has the 785 features as input